# Merge a collection with duplicate objects and update some properties with LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a collection of objects of type 'OrganisationUnit'

```
   Id   Index
    A   1
    B   2
    C   3
    D   4
    E   5
    F   6
    G   7
```

**Id F** is moved before **Id B**

I have the both Id`s F and B as extra OrganisationUnit objects available passed from another layer.

What happens now:

The **Id F** gets the **Index** of **Id B**.
**Id B** and all **following Id`s** have to increment their Index by 1

The result should look like this:

```
Id  Index
A   1
F   2
B   3
C   4
D   5
E   6
G   7
```

How would you do the merge the 2 objects with the collection (containing already those 2 objects) and do the updates with the index property with LINQ?

Comment: With a couple of conditionals and a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit Linq and a simple loop:

```
var f = units.First(u => u.ID == "F");
int newFIndex = 2;
var updateUnits = units
    .Where(u => u.Index >= newFIndex && u.Index < f.Index)
    .ToList();
foreach (OrganisationUnit u in updateUnits)
    u.Index++;
f.Index = newFIndex;
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/bVjYm7)

Comment: argh... sorry I forgot something... First thing is the u.Index < f.Index is not correct because all Index properties after the newFIndex which is 2 must be incremented by 1. Second thing on my side: the units collection and the predicate has a >= newFIndex that would mean the unit f and its Index is also incremented in the updateUnits by 1 up to 3. That would not be correct.

Comment: @Elisa: Have you seen the demo? That is exactly yor desired result, isn't it? Why should the units after the "f-unit" be incremented? They are not affected by the swap operation, only the  units in the range of the units that are swapped. For instance, a unit with index=8 would keep it's old index since the count of units before remains the same. The same is true for the units before the new-index, they keep their old index.

Comment: Sorry Tim I have only understood your code when I implemented it and saw it live. And I got confused about sth else I better do not tell here ;-) Thank you your solution works as it should be.